# Flutter SteamBuilder snapshot.data is null

Tags: flutter, dart, snapshot

I am new to flutter. I am trying to use SteamBuilder to retrieve snapshot data.
But snapshot.data is returning null.
     snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done 
is false.
    snapshot.hasData
is false.

This is the dart file in which I am trying to retrieve snapshot data

```
return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
        stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          //print(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done);
          //print(snapshot.data);
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            print('snapshot has data');
            UserData userData = snapshot.data;
            return Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Update your brew settings.',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    initialValue: userData.name,
                    decoration: textInputDecorator,
                    validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Please enter a name' : null,
                    onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentName = val),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  DropdownButtonFormField(
                    value: _currentSugars ?? userData.sugars,
                    decoration: textInputDecorator,
                    items: sugars.map((sugar) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: sugar,
                        child: Text('$sugar sugars'),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentSugars = val ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Slider(
                    value: _currentStrength.toDouble() ?? userData.strength,
                    activeColor: Colors.brown[_currentStrength ?? userData.strength],
                    inactiveColor: Colors.brown[_currentStrength ?? userData.strength],
                    min: 100.0,
                    max: 900.0,
                    divisions: 8,
                    onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentStrength = val.round()),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.pink[400],
                      child: Text(
                        'Update',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        print(_currentName);
                        print(_currentSugars);
                        print(_currentStrength);
                      }
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            print('snapshot doesnt have data');
            return Loading();
          }
        }
    );
```

This is the stream

```
Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return brewCollection.document(uid).snapshots().map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }
```

brewCollection-

```
  final CollectionReference brewCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('brews');
```

_userDataFromSnapshot

```
UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserData(
      uid: uid,
      name: snapshot.data['name'],
      sugars: snapshot.data['sugars'],
      strength: snapshot.data['strength']
    );
  }
```

UserData

```
class UserData {

  final String uid;
  final String name;
  final String strength;
  final int sugars;

  UserData({ this.uid, this.sugars, this.strength, this.name });
}
```

Since I am new to Flutter I don't know how to approach this issue.
Please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UserData class should have been

```
class UserData {

  final String uid;
  final String name;
  final int strength; // type int not String
  final String sugars; // type String not int

  UserData({ this.uid, this.sugars, this.strength, this.name });
}
```

I got confused with datatypes of strength and sugars. My bad.
It was a stupid mistake.

Thank you for responding :)

Answer (score 1):

Normally you need to check 3 cases:

- snapshot is null (before any stream or action is fired, usually right
  when the Widget is created)
- snapshot is not null and data is null/invalid (stream is registered but no data is emitted yet)
- snapshot is not null and data is valid (received data)

Comment: Before widget is created, after StreamBuilder in builder:
snapshot.data - is returning null. You can see the commented line in the code.
I guess snapshot is null.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have not handle error so it will be difficult to know what happens by just seeing code so also catch error on snapshot as

```
if(snapshot.hasData){


  //Show widget with data

 }else if(snapshot.hasError){
   return Center(
     child:Text(snapshot.error.toString());
   );

 }else{
   return CircularProgressIndicator();
 }
```

Comment: snapshot.error.toString() is returning - 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'
How to handle this error?